# Making main page background image fill screen in react

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I have a react app with router. I also have a navbar.
I want my main page to have a background image that fills the entire page:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.Main .bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../resources/top-bg6.jpeg");
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

However, this causes the image to be cropped at height 56px.
I think the cause is all the encapsulating divs that are caused by the different components and the router.

If I try

```
.Main .bg {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
  ...
}
```

A scroll bar appears. I do I deal with it?
Edit: Added a screenshot:
[image: snapshot of divs]

Comment: The scrollbar is likely due to browser defaults that set a `margin` on `body`. Have you tried `body { margin: 0; }`?

Comment: There's a good chance that the main area has a top margin or there's padding on its parent element that is intended to push the main element into full view below the nav. Without seeing the resulting markup there's really no way to know.  Use the developer tools to inspect the resulting page.

Comment: Added a screen shot. It seems this is caused by the fact that each react component inserts a div. And so, the main is nested inside many divs, for example, the router, the root and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's all is great but a little bit you have change in your code.
Apply 100vh height on your .Main div only and change .bg background-position = center.
Now your image come at centre of your background .it's depend on your image size.